# I can't insert data into a table in Sequelize (foreign keys specifically)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

So I'm using Sequelize for my PostgreSQL database on my JavaScript app. I have 4 models (Users, Posts, Likes, and FollowingsFollowers). My Users model works fine, it doesn't have any foreign keys so I'm able to create and find data with no problems whatsoever. However, my Posts model has 2 foreign keys (user_id and parent_id). user_id references the primary key (id) from the Users table and parent_id references the primary key (id) from itself (the Posts table). When I try to insert data into the Posts table I'm able to insert data on the regular fields, but the foreign keys are simply ignored.

Here is my database connection:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const API = require('../../client/public/config.js');
const db = new Sequelize(API.elephantSqlUrl);

db.authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

module.exports = db;
```

Here is my Users model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../db.js');

const Users = db.define('users', {
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true
  },
  bio: Sequelize.STRING,
  profile_picture: Sequelize.STRING
});

module.exports = Users;
```

Here is my Posts model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../db.js');

const Posts = db.define('posts', {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  body: Sequelize.STRING,
  likesCount: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0
  }
});

module.exports = Posts;
```

Here is where I define the foreign keys and sync my database:

```
const db = require('./db.js');
const Users = require('./models/users.js');
const Posts = require('./models/posts.js');
const Likes = require('./models/likes.js');
const FollowingsFollowers = require('./models/followingsFollowers.js');

Posts.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
Users.hasMany(Posts, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
Posts.belongsTo(Posts, { foreignKey: 'parent_id' });
Posts.hasMany(Posts, { foreignKey: 'parent_id' });
Likes.belongsTo(Posts, { foreignKey: 'post_id' });
Posts.hasMany(Likes, { foreignKey: 'post_id' });
Likes.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
Users.hasMany(Likes, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
FollowingsFollowers.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: 'following_id' });
Users.hasMany(FollowingsFollowers, { foreignKey: 'following_id' });
FollowingsFollowers.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: 'follower_id' });
Users.hasMany(FollowingsFollowers, { foreignKey: 'follower_id' });

db.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('db synced');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('error syncing db');
  });
```

and this is where I try to add a Post:

```
const addPost = (username, post) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Users.findOne({ where: { username: username } })
      .then((user) => {
        post.user_id = user.id;

        Posts.create()
          .then((created) => {
            resolve();
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

When I call this function with a username and an object with "type" and "body" keys, a Post is created. However, the Post contains an "id", a "type", a "body", a "likesCount", a "createdAt", and an "updatedAt" fields. The "user_id" field never gets added in there.

Comment: your `Post` model does not contain a user / userId attribute

Comment: you mean as part of define? i know the field is there cause when i sync i get a message showing my table and both user_id and parent_id fields are in there

Comment: yes but i think some features do not work correctly without setting those attributes - i usually use `sequelize-typescript` and i always define foreign keys in the model

Comment: would you mind showing me an example? ive been searching this problem for 3 days now with no luck. anything would help

Comment: https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript#model-association - i use this one and it works nice in my projects. But of course this is written in typescript

Comment: Adding foreign key fields in model definition is NOT required, with properly defined relations it should work. Are you 100% sure that your db schema contains `user_id` field and its empty for newly created Post?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is gonna solve your problem, but you don't pass any parameter to `create()` method. `post` object is passed to function, enriched with `user_id` and... ignored.

Shouldn't it be like this?:

```
(...)
Posts.create(post)
(...)
```

Comment: idk why that wasnt there, you're absolutely right that post should be passed in to the create function. however, that wasnt the general problem, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it. My solution was to add foreign key relations on my model files, like so:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Users = require('./users.js');
const db = require('../db.js');

const Posts = db.define('posts', {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  body: Sequelize.STRING,
  likesCount: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0
  }
});

Posts.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
Posts.belongsTo(Posts, { foreignKey: 'parent_id' });

module.exports = Posts;
```

and then for the file where i sync my db, thats all i would do, like so:

```
const db = require('./db.js');
const Users = require('./models/users.js');
const Posts = require('./models/posts.js');
const Likes = require('./models/likes.js');
const FollowingsFollowers = require('./models/followingsfollowers.js');

db.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('db synced');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('error syncing db');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Add user_id as foreign key in posts model and other models where realtion with users required.
2.Define your Posts models as:
const Posts = db.define('posts', {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  user_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  body: Sequelize.STRING,
  likesCount: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0
  }
});
3. Remove Posts.belongsTo(Posts, { foreignKey: 'parent_id' }); not required
```